Help with zero order Hankel Transform of a Complex Function
I'm trying to calculate the zero order Hankel transform of the following function:
$()=\log(^2⋅^2)⋅\exp(−⋅⋅^2)$.
Where $B$ is a real positive constant and $k$ is a real number.
We may write the logarithm as  $\left. \frac{\partial (B^2 r^2)^Z}{\partial Z}\right|_{z=0}$, then the zero order Hankel transform of the following function will help me,too:
$()=(^2⋅^2)^z⋅\exp(−⋅⋅^2)$.
Can anyone assist me in calculating this transform? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your attention!

With  help of Mathematica:
$\mathcal{H}_{r,v}\left[\log \left(B^2 r^2\right) \exp \left(-i k r^2\right)\right](s)=\\\underset{z\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\mathcal{H}_{r,v}\left[\left(B^2 r^2\right)^z \exp \left(-i k r^2\right)\right](s)=\\\underset{z\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{(-1)^{\frac{1}{4} (-v-2 (1+z))} 2^{-1-v} B^{2 z} k^{-1-\frac{v}{2}-z} s^v \Gamma \left(1+\frac{v}{2}+z\right) \, _1F_1\left(1+\frac{v}{2}+z;1+v;-\frac{s^2}{4 \sqrt{-k} \sqrt{k}}\right)}{\Gamma
   (1+v)}=\\-\frac{(-1)^{-\frac{v}{4}} 2^{-2-v} k^{-1-\frac{v}{2}} s^v \Gamma \left(1+\frac{v}{2}\right) \left(\, _1F_1\left(\frac{2+v}{2};1+v;-\frac{s^2}{4 \sqrt{-k^2}}\right) \left(\pi +4 i \log (B)-2 i \log (k)+2 i \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{v}{2}\right)\right)+2 i \text{Hypergeometric1F1}^{(1,0,0)}\left(\frac{2+v}{2},1+v,-\frac{s^2}{4 \sqrt{-k^2}}\right)\right)}{\Gamma (1+v)}$
Mathematica code:
HoldForm[ Limit[D[((-1)^(1/4 (-v - 2 (1 + z))) 2^(-1 - v) B^(2 z) k^(-1 - v/2 - z) s^v*  Gamma[1 + v/2 + z] Hypergeometric1F1[1 + v/2 + z,  1 + v, -(s^2/(4 Sqrt[-k] Sqrt[k]))])/Gamma[1 + v], z],  z -> 0] == -((2^(-2 - v)*k^(-1 - v/2)*s^v* Gamma[1 +  v/2]*(Hypergeometric1F1[(2 + v)/2,  1 + v, -1/4* s^2/Sqrt[-k^2]]*(Pi + (4*I)*Log[B] - (2*I)*Log[k] + (2*I)* PolyGamma[0, 1 + v/2]) + (2*I)* Derivative[1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric1F1][(2 + v)/2,  1 + v, -1/4*s^2/Sqrt[-k^2]]))/((-1)^(v/4)*Gamma[1 + v]))]
